# Filter images from folder given 2 dateTime range

Tags: php

I'm at a loss with the algorithm to use to filter an array of files between 2 date-time ranges. I managed to read the files from my image folder into an array and sort it and even display them in ascending order in terms of time and date modified. However, I'm trying to have a filter which will allow me to list the files from a date-time to a date-time. I've done some research but to no avail. Maybe I'm looking at the wrong place. Would reall appreciate someone to unblock me on this.

Here's my code:

```
$files = glob('../*.jpg');
    usort($files, function($a, $b) {
        return filemtime($a) > filemtime($b);
    });

    foreach($files as $file){
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($file . date('F d Y, H:i:s', filemtime($file)));
      echo '</pre>';
    }

    $startTime = strtotime( '2016-12-17 12:00' );
    $endTime = strtotime( '2016-12-17 12:30' );
```

Comment: It looks like you have a typo in the end time, did you mean '2016-12-17 12:30' ?

Comment: Place this in the loop `if( (filemtime($file)>=$startTime && filemtime($file)<=$endTime) === false) continue;` , place the variable creation before the loop.

Comment: @TomaszSwider Yep, sorry typo i here. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
$start = strtotime( '2016-12-17 12:00' );
$end = strtotime( '2016-12-17 12:30' );

foreach($files as $file){
   $fileTime = filemtime($file);

   if($start < $fileTime && $fileTime < $end) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($file . date('F d Y, H:i:s', filemtime($file)));
    echo '</pre>';
   }
```

}